# RenderAction a list of a model in the layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, renderaction

So I want to put a list of newsitems in _Layout.cshtml
I have a News model and a Show Action in its controller, and I want to put it in there with a RenderAction.

```
@Html.RenderAction("Show","News");
```

Does not seem to work.
But http://localhost:49295/News/Show/ does work
I should be using renderaction right?

EDIT

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Show","News");}
```

stackoverflowerror, probably because I just put an action that uses the layout, in the layout itself? How do I not use the default layout for this view?

Comment: "Does not seem to work" => what happens? The part in question is just not rendered or do you get an exception? In case of an exception what is the message / stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the layout to null in the View

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

Comment: Thanks, will remember that. I'm not used to MVC yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your View try:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Show","News");}
```